# What is ScanPointRevalidation finding from SQL Assessment API?

Tags: sql-server-2019

Ran the [SQL Assessment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-assessment-api/sql-assessment-api-overview) and one of the findings was:

Low -Review clustered index placement to reduce Scan Point Revalidations/sec (289.34)

Not sure what this finding is instructing me to do.  What is a Scan Point Revalidation?